# Karate summary reports not showing all tested features in the Karate-summary.html report file

Tags: karate

[image]Karate summary reports not showing all tested features, it is updated the latest executions in the karate-summary.html though all the executions are created each individual html files.

I have two features print1.feature and print2.feaure, when run the test with latest karate version 1.4.1, it is generating the karate-summary.html report with print2.feature only instead of both the features.

Same thing I have checked with karate version 0.9.6, it is capturing both the features report in karate-summary.html file. Please find the attachment. Please provide the solution, if it is available.

Thanks in advance.

Karate summary reports not showing all tested features, it is updated the latest executions in the karate-summary.html though all the executions are created each individual html files.

I have two features print1.feature and print2.feaure, when run the test with latest karate version 1.4.1, it is generating the karate-summary.html report with print2.feature only instead of both the features.

Same thing I have checked with karate version 0.9.6, it is capturing both the features report in karate-summary.html file. Please find the attachment. Please provide the solution, if it is available.

Comment: the only way to get any help in this situation is please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I see 2 features print.feature and print2.feature, listed in the report, so unsure what the issue is exactly.  Do you really have 3 features, and are missing the print1.feature results?  Have you verified tags associated with your runner/run commands (no @ignore tag)?  More info needed...sorry